# GRASS iterate over multiple shapefiles using g.region

Tags: grass-gis, shell

I have a shapefile called `Ahmednagar`. I have daily rainfall data from 1997 till 2008. I want to sum total rainfall from 152 till 273 day for each year for 1997 till 2008. This is how I do it.

```
g.region vect=Ahmednagar  #first set g.region as Ahmednagar
j=1997
while [ $j != 2008 ]
do
    r.mapcalc "tmpsum=0.0"
    i=152                   #start from 152 day of the year
    while [ $i != 274 ]     # till the 273 day of the year
    do
            g.copy rast=prec$j.$i,tmp #copies rainfall of jth year and ith day
            r.mapcalc "tmpsum2 = tmpsum+ tmp"
            r.mapcalc "tmpsum=tmpsum2"
            g.remove rast=tmp
            i=`expr $i + 1`
    done
    g.rename rast=tmpsum,precAhmednagar$j   #rename the tmpsum as the shapefile
    j=`expr $j + 1`
done
```

This will give me a raster files for each year from 1997 till 2007 called `precAhmednagar$j` where j is the year.

Now I have many more shapefiles (215 exactly). For each of them I want to do the same thing. But I am not sure how to go about it. Basically set a shapefile using `g.region`, do all the calculation and most importantly rename the final raster `tmpsum` as the `precXXXX$j` where XXXX is the name of the shapefile.

I have imported all the 215 shapefiles in GRASS the list which I can get using `g.list vect` but that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered yourself quickly, but I'd like to add two comments:

1.To do the loop you asked for, I would just replace the shapefile name with a variable, then go thru all shapefile names and run the script with each. For example (based on your first solution above:

```
V=$1
g.region vect=${V}  #first set g.region to shapefile
j=1997
  while [ $j != 2008 ]
  do
    r.mapcalc "tmpsum=0.0"
    i=152
      while [ $i != 274 ]
      do
      g.copy rast=prec$j.$i,tmp #copies rainfall of jth year and ith day
      r.mapcalc "tmpsum2 = tmpsum+ tmp"
      r.mapcalc "tmpsum=tmpsum2"
      g.remove rast=tmp
      i=`expr $i + 1`
    done
  g.rename rast=tmpsum,prec${V}${j}
  j=`expr $j + 1`
done
```

Now put the above into a shell script (i.e. sum_precip.sh) then do

```
for v in `g.list vect`; do
sum_precip.sh $v
done
```

2. **BUT**: when you set the region to a shapefile, the region settings cover the **whole bounding box** of the vector. Consider, for example, the country of Croatia. Since it is "curved" the bounding box will be **much** larger than the polygon boundary of the country. Then the new raster that is created for that region will also be much larger than the polygon. In the above process you will certainly be getting total precip twice or more for some areas where the rasters are overlapping.

If you have daily rainfall in each shapefile, why do you need to create some intermediate raster at all? I would just import the precip data from all shapefiles into a spatial database, then do a query to total all precip for day numbers between your 152 and 273 interval, for each polygon.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have the same concern you raised in point 2. Actually the rainfall data I have is gridded (0.5°) whereas 215 polygons are districts that are of different area. That's why I wanted to set each g.region and calculate rainfall of the bounding box which would represent rainfall for that polygon. But like you said the shape of polygons would result in spurious rainfall values which I need to check later on. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a shortcut way to do this. I rename all my 215 shapefiles as numbers appneded with a text (`x1.shp`, `x2.shp`, `x3.shp`...`x215.shp`) and imported them in GRASS. Than I used this loop to change my g.region:

```
k=1
while [ $k != 216 ]
do
     g.region vect=x$k
     j=1997
     while [ $j != 2008 ]
     do
          ..............   #rest of the code here
     done
     k=`expr $k + 1`
done
```